# how to insert arabic characters in database?

Tags: django, database, sqlite

I'm a Django beginner student that doesn't have much experiences with database
since my country uses Arabic characters , I tried to add some Arabic words in my database instead of Eng., but even when I was typing it in shell (sqlite3) it showed it as `???`
how can I insert a word like`مرد‍‍` into database .
also if database doesn't show it correctly why when I add a comment through site in Arabic letters it works perfect?

Comment: Which OS is this on? If you're on Windows, chances are your terminal session isn't in unicode; try `chcp 65001` to change the session's codepage to UTF-8 before running `sqlite3`.

Comment: @AKX same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/unicode/) it supports Unicode data everywhere. You don't need to do anything when Creating `Arabic characters` in the database using **SQLite**. if you are on windows 10 just run  **`chcp 1256`** in the cmd to change code page  session to `Code Page 1256 Windows Arabic` .  if it didn't work just use the Django admin to create your database

Comment: it did work thank you but all letters were separated and left align  like ```درم‍‍ ``` instead of ```مرد``` can i fix it?

Comment: Yeah it's the same for me I really don't know how to make it straight